# Frequent BSOD on Windows 7 machine. Error attached

Tags: windows-7, freeze, crash, bsod

[image]

This randomly happens everyday. Sometimes while browsing the web. Sometimes in excel. Sometimes in sublime. Sometimes in my CMD prompt.

Here's what happens in order:

1. Screen/cursor will freeze.
2. If playing music it will start to static/spaz out.
3. Then comes the BSOD
4. Hard reset from tower to get back on. (System realizes it crashed)

Any ideas how I can solve this because I am very close to just throwing this machine out my window. I hit `CTRL+S` almost every minute in case it decides to crap out on me.

**DMP**

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 040314-11356-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 4/3/2014 12:02:04 AM
Bug Check String  : KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001e
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : tcpip.sys
Caused By Address : tcpip.sys+4c0df
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+75b90
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\040314-11356-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 290,880
Dump File Time    : 4/3/2014 12:03:45 AM
==================================================
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Replace the CMOS battery.

Comment: @Ramhound why? Please explain

Comment: Because of the message in the BSOD.  Sadly if it's not the battery it's the CPU.

Comment: @Ramhound Ok $3 is worth a try. Thanks.

Comment: do you overclock the CPU?

Comment: @magic no I haven't

Comment: update the BIOS/UEFI

Comment: @magic running latest bios

Comment: upload the dmp file

Comment: @magic updated question. Still trying to figure out what tcpip.sys ... btw 4/3 is not the last crash but this is the only thing reporting in BlueScreenView

Comment: I need the dmp and now the crappy output of BlueScreenView.

Comment: @magic how do I get the dmp that you need?

Comment: @magicandre1981: I assume he'll not get a dump - or have you ever managed to take a photograph of the blue screen during the time it is initializing the disk? I only managed that in cases where the disk could not be initialized and it's waiting forever.

Comment: copy the minidump folder (C:\Windows\Minidump) to the desktop, zip the folder, put the zip on a cloud service and post a link here.

Answer (score 2):

The DRIVER_VERIFIER_IOMANAGER_VIOLATION (c9) bugcheck is caused by the driver Xeno7x64.sys:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_VERIFIER_IOMANAGER_VIOLATION (c9)
The IO manager has caught a misbehaving driver.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000213, The caller has changed the status field of an IRP it does not understand.
Arg2: fffff88006e94c02, The address in the driver's code where the error was detected.
Arg3: fffff98008258e10, IRP address.
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0xc9_213

DRIVER_VERIFIER_IO_VIOLATION_TYPE:  213

FAULTING_IP: 
Xeno7x64+1c02
fffff880`06e94c02 8bd8            mov     ebx,eax

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
Xeno7x64+1c02
fffff880`06e94c02 8bd8            mov     ebx,eax

IRP_ADDRESS: fffff98008258e10

DEVICE_OBJECT: fffffa8015337990

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VERIFIER_ENABLED_VISTA_MINIDUMP

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17029 (debuggers(dbg).140219-1702) amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff800039094ec to fffff8000347cbc0

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!VerifierBugCheckIfAppropriate
nt!ViErrorFinishReport
nt!VfErrorReport1
nt!ViGenericVerifyIrpStackDownward
nt!VfMajorVerifyIrpStackDownward
nt!IovpCallDriver1
nt!VfBeforeCallDriver
nt!IovCallDriver
Xeno7x64
0x0
0x0


IMAGE_NAME:  Xeno7x64.sys

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xc9_213_VRF_Xeno7x64+1c02

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0xc9_213_vrf_xeno7x64+1c02

    Loaded symbol image file: Xeno7x64.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\Xeno7x64.sys
    Image name: Xeno7x64.sys
    Timestamp:        Wed Dec 08 18:22:48 2010 (4CFFBEE8)
```

Update the driver for your Bigfoot Networks Killer(TM) PCI-E Gaming Adapter.

The other bugcheck is caused by the driver mvs91xx.sys:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED (1e)
This is a very common bugcheck.  Usually the exception address pinpoints
the driver/function that caused the problem.  Always note this address
as well as the link date of the driver/image that contains this address.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, The exception code that was not handled
Arg2: 0000000000000000, The address that the exception occurred at
Arg3: 0000000000000000, Parameter 0 of the exception
Arg4: 0000000000000000, Parameter 1 of the exception

Debugging Details:
------------------

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x1E

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  7

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17029 (debuggers(dbg).140219-1702) amd64fre

DPC_STACK_BASE:  FFFFF88003528FB0

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  fffff88003528b58 -- (.exr 0xfffff88003528b58)
ExceptionAddress: fffff880014ad67e (mvs91xx+0x000000000000367e)
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8000347a5be to fffff80003482b90

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheck
nt!KiKernelCalloutExceptionHandler
nt!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
nt!RtlDispatchException
nt!KiDispatchException
nt!KiExceptionDispatch
nt!KiBreakpointTrap
mvs91xx
mvs91xx
0x0
0x0



STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
mvs91xx+367f
fffff880`014ad67f ??              ???

IMAGE_NAME:  mvs91xx.sys

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x1E_mvs91xx+367f

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x1e_mvs91xx+367f

    Loaded symbol image file: mvs91xx.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\mvs91xx.sys
    Image name: mvs91xx.sys
    Timestamp:        Tue Aug 09 05:05:23 2011
```

This is the Marvell-AHCI-driver. Also update this one.

Comment: Thanks. Quick update. My Bigfoot network driver is latest. (no new updates available) and The only Marvell I have is Marvell 91xx SATA 6G Controller (storage controller) and it also latest update. So I can't update either as they already are latest versions. Do you have any other advice? Thanks again.

Comment: the latest Marvell is from 2013: http://driveroff.net/soft/massmarvell6g/. try this LAN driver: http://driveroff.net/soft/lanbigfoot/

Comment: Ok I updated to latest drivers. Will report back if I get another BSOD crash. Thanks +1 for the help will accept if I don't crash again.

Comment: Where did you get the dump from?

Comment: looks like he deleted the link. He posted it in a comment.

Comment: @magic Sorry to bother you. System seemed to running smoothly for past two days but just froze and required hard reboot just now. NO BSOD this time. Just frozen. Reset from tower after waiting 2 minutes. Any advice? Thanks

Comment: check all steps from scenario 3: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504

Answer (score -1):

There's something seriously wrong with your PC. You either have sever driver problems or hardware problems.

The Screenshot you posted is [Bugcheck 0x0101](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This can be caused by hardware failures or possible by a buggy driver putting the CPU in a strage state.

The Dump information you posted in text format contains [Bugcheck 0x01e](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which looks more like a buggy driver. Might be the same as for the screenshot, but might be a different one.

All that means that you have had different blue screen crashes within a short time frame, which is a bad indicator.

My suggestion: activate driver verifier. Press <kbd>Win+R</kbd> and type `verifier`, choose default settings. Note that this will make your PC (significantly) slower, but instead of strange blue screens you'll get the name of the buggy driver at next blue screen (given it actually is a buggy driver).

And hopefully it will be able to write another dump file to disk, which you can then uplaod for us to analyze. Also consider submitting this information to Microsoft, because this may result in a pretty good suggestion what to do.

**Update:**

The next bluescreen is [Bugcheck 0x00C9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). 213 means

> The caller has changed the status field of an IRP it does not understand. (IRP specified.)

That doesn't tell me much. However, the suggested repair action is "System files integrity check and repair". That probably refers to `sfc /scannow`. Note that you might need to run this up to 3 times to repair everything.

If that doesn't help, you probably should create a backup of the hard disk using another PC and then reinstall the OS from scratch.

Comment: Thanks I will try this and report back what is causing the BSOD. Hopefully it is a buggy driver and verifier will catch it. Hoping it's not hardware related. I'm guessing you don't think this is a CMOS battery issue? I will report back once I have more information. Thanks

Comment: @feed_me_code: As I said, it could be a hardware problem as well. Bug while I've had many empty CMOS batteries, I never had bluescreens because of that. I assume (but I'm not so sure), that in case the PC is running, the clock timer is powered by the power supply, not by the CMOS battery.

Comment: followed your advice and restarted. Got the error message above. See updated question. Pic attached. Thanks

Comment: I can't boot in to Windows now. See updated screenshot. I haven't added any new hardware. How do I get back on? BSOD on startup .

Comment: I'm in system recovery options. It's trying to boot from my d drive instead of my c drive. How do I get out of this diagnostic mode and restart normally? It gives five options. Startup repair doesn't work. I also have cmd prompt . How can I get out of this mode?

Comment: @feed_me_code: Start the PC in safe mode (Press F8 at boot time), run verifier again and choose "delete existing settings"

Comment: @feed_me_code: It should also be possible to type `verifier /reset` at the command prompt

Comment: ok back on normal mode now. So from those updated screenshots.. Do you have any idea what the culprit is here?

Comment: @feed_me_code: See my updated answer. Sorry I have to leave now, it's past midnight here.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just an update scan results: `Beginning verification phase of system scan. / Verification 100% complete. / Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.`